# Simple JavaScript regex needed to skip characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some regex code which converts any url i.e. `http://www.url.com` in a string into a hyperlink i.e. `<a href='http://www.url.com'>http://www.url.com</a>`

Regex code:

```
var exp = /(\b(https?|):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;   
toReturn = toReturn.replace(exp,"<a target='_blank' href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

However I don't want it to search/replace between some characters specifically [img][/img]

**Note: `[img][/img]` and urls may be in the string numerous times.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you putting back an <A> tag even though you didn't start with one?

Answer (score 1):

It would be very tricky to do with just a regexp. This is because regular expressions can only match [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)*, and it's unlikely that any language which has open/close tags will be regular.

(* in practice, the “regular expressions” in most programming languages aren't actually regular, and have facilities for matching more complex languages… But I have rarely found these facilities useful, and I don't think they are worth using for this problem).

A better method would be to write a simple parser which splits the input based on the tags, then only runs your regular expression against the parts which could contain URLs.

For example, something like:

```
function fix_urls(str) {
    var result = [];
    var url_re = /\bhttp:…/g;
    var tag_re = /(\[\/?[a-zA-Z]+\])/g;
    var split = str.split(tag_re);
    var in_tag = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i += 1) {
        var part = split[i];
        if (part.search(tag_re) == 0) {
            if (part[1] == "/")
                in_tag -= 1;
            else
                in_tag += 1;
        } else if (in_tag == 0) {
            part = part.replace(url_re, "<a …>…</a>");
        }
        result.push(part);
    }
    return result.join("");
 }
```

Comment: **WRONG!!!** No one apart from RE2 uses regular expressions in the OLD-SCHOOL sense anymore.  As soon as you have something like `([a-z]+).*\1` you have a non-regular language, which cannot be solved with a DFA because of the auxiliarly storage needs.  Real-world patterns used everywhere in the last 20-30 years match non-regular languages perfectly fine. Please please please please stop beating this dead horse. It is not true.  It is not even close to true.

Comment: Right... so is there a solution for the question or is it still impossible?

Comment: @tchrist: please forgive my lack of precision. You are entirely correct that, yes, current implementations of regular expressions are not at all regular. However, I have yet to see that capability used (let alone in a sane way) anywhere except documentations and examples. I'd be happy to be proved wrong, though, so if you'd like to write a less-regular expression that can answer the question, I'd  be the first to upvote it.

Comment: @James: as I've noted in my amended answer, it may be possible, but I wouldn't advise it. If I had to solve that problem, I would use a little function like the one in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When needing context sensitive editing, *global replace* is simply the wrong approach. You may use a *scanner* that finds consecutive *tokens*, then in your loop output some tokens unchanged, and some edited. I cannot find how to do this with standard javascript or its regexp methods. If you find a javascript Tokenizer where you define tokens using regexp or similar, you are almost there.